# Convert Reactive Form Values to Model property types

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Using Angular 8 I have a component with a form to create a post.

The post model has 3 properties: one string, one boolean and one number:

```
export interface PostModel {
  title: string
  year: number;
  approved: Boolean;  
}
```

The problem is when I create the PostModel from form values everything is considered a string:

```
  let model: PostModel = { 
    title: this.form.value.title,
    approved: this.form.value.approved,
    year: this.form.value.year
  };
```

How to create a PostModel from form values and using the PostModel property types?

This is the component code:

```
export class PostCreateComponent extends Modal implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({  
      title: [''],
      year: [''],
      approved: ['']
    });

  }

onSubmit() {

  if (this.form.valid) {

    let model: PostModel = { 
      title: this.form.value.title,
      approved: this.form.value.approved,
      year: this.form.value.year
    };

    // Create post

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did you use in your html type="number" ?
2. I would recommend you converting it if the previous step didn't work

```
value: number = +year;
// The + is for converting a string to a number
```

Comment: 1. No. But there are other types where I think I don't have an equivalente in HTML. 2. Yes, that is what I tried. I was wondering if there was a better way because of bigger models.

Comment: @MiguelMoura I took a quick look at the Angular documentation API and I don't seem to find any other quick solution. I looked at other example codes and they do the same thing as you and me use.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately type of `FormControl` value is just `any`. But, a workaround might be to extend the class and add the type restriction:

```js
class TypedFormControl<T> extends FormControl {
    get value(): T | null {
        return super.value;
    }

    get valueChanges(): Observable<T | null> {
        return super.valueChanges;
    }
}

export class PostCreateComponent {
    readonly yearControl = new TypedFormControl<number>();
    readonly form = new FormGroup({
        year: this.yearControl,
        ...
    })

    ...

    onSubmit() {
        ...
        const post: PostModel = {
            year: this.yearControl.value,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```